# How to change the label of an Address field type sub value?

Tags: address, label

I have a field on an object that is an Address.

[image]

When the user clicks on the address to edit it, it shows the various sub-fields in the address, including a a field labeled "Zip".

[image]

I would like to change the label for the "Zip" box.   There's nothing in Rename Tabs and Labels that seems relevant.  I see the that I can change the label of the address field, but not the sub-fields that you get when you edit the address.  Is there any way to do this?

(Note: I can change the Zip label for addresses on the Account or Contact object but not this object, which happens to be OrderSummary)

[image]

Comment: You should be able to rename the individual elements of the compound field further down in the list of fields under Rename Tabs and Labels. Under billing address you should also have Billing City, Billing Country, etc. that give you the ability to do this.

Comment: @CallumMacErlich. Thanks but... nope, there's definitely nothing like that in there.  I do see that in the Account object and the Contact object but not this object (OrderSummary).

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, it is not possible to change the labels on those fields.

"You can’t rename the labels for the individual components of a custom address field."
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fields_caf_requirements.htm&type=5